# Different text color for each collaborator

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, collaboration, textcolor

At work we use Google Spreadsheets for mutual communication. Everyone has their own textcolor that they are allowed to work in the document.

But everyone forgets to customize the text color. Since it is not convenient to select a textcolor each time we want to work in Google Spreadsheeds, we had the idead to automate this with Google Script Editor.

```
function setFontColor(range, fontc) {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   var cell = sheet.getRange(range);
   cell.setFontColor(fontc);
 }

function onEdit() {

  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  if (email == "user1@company.com"){
    setFontColor(".getActiveCell()", "#FF8800");
  }

  if (email == "user2@company.com"){
    setFontColor(".getActiveCell()", "#0099CC");
  }

  if (email == "user3@company.com"){
    setFontColor(".getActiveCell()", "#9933CC");
  }

  if (email == "user4@company.com"){
    setFontColor(".getActiveCell()", "#CC0000");
  }

}
```

I came up with this script since I couldn't find anything else. Unfortunately this isn't working. Can someone help me to make it work or give me a link to a existing script?

It would really help me! And probably allot of others.

Comment: what's the setFontcolor() look like that you are calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and wanted to share it for anyone who might think it would be helpfull!

```
  function onEdit() {

  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ActiveRow = ActiveSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var ActiveCell = ActiveSheet.getActiveCell();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  if (email == "user1@company.com"){
    ActiveCell.setFontColor("#FF8800");
  }

  if (email == "user2@company.com"){
    ActiveCell.setFontColor("#0099CC");
  }

  if (email == "user3@company.com"){
    ActiveCell.setFontColor("#9933CC");
  }

  if (email == "user4@company.com"){
    ActiveCell.setFontColor("#CC0000");
  }
}
```

Comment: onEdit id indeed a better idea since I can't see any way to change the global property of fontColor for the "current session". Nice little program ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax errors in you code provided. Try changing this way and run the code:

```
function onOpen() {

  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  if (email == "user1@company.com"){
    setFontcolor("#FF8800");
  }

  if (email == "user2@company.com"){
    setFontcolor("#0099CC");
  }
}
```

Also you have to get the range of values for which you want to change the color and then use setFontcolor() method. You can refer to this page for more information: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFontColor(String)
Hope that helps!

Comment: I've changed the original code but it's not working. I did call the onEdit, and it then should get the activecell.